# Multiple comparisons with binary data: Hsu's MCB method

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, binary-data

Given a factor with a number of levels, say for example, versions of a banner advertisement on a web page, where the measurement of interest is the click through rate (# clicks / # of times banner add was viewed), is there a principled way to determine the best performing ad, controlling for multiple testing?

Hsu's [Multiple Comparisons with the Best](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat502/node/34) appears like the perfect solution (but it works for normally distributed continuous data). Does anyone know of an analog for binary response data? Preferably in R and preferably in a glm context where covariates could be controlled for. This last piece is not vital however as the experiment will be randomized and a one-way situation should be adequate.

Comment: You have framed this as an estimation problem (find the best) but are suggesting you want to do hypothesis testing.  In the absence of a prior distribution, the best guess you can make of the level that is best is the one that appears the best in testing: it's that simple.  In other words, choose the ad with the highest click-through rate.

Comment: @whuber. Hello. How is my question different than an experiment to see which of ten fertilizers produces the greatest yield in a classic DOE?  A one-way-anova with a continuous distribution is used to test if each mu_i differs from the max of the other mu (instead of simply differing because of sampling variation) - how is this different? If I had only two versions (coded 1/0), I would compare them  - potentially in a logistic regression framework. I could do the same here but would have issues with all the comparison.

Comment: @B The answer is that you're asking a different question.  You're not trying to decide whether there are significant differences among different options; you simply need to make the best decision possible, based on these data, concerning which is the best.  Suppose you had to answer to the head of advertising, who wants your decision: which is "the best performing ad?"  Are you going to tell her you don't know because some statistical test suggests the difference between best and second best could be due to chance?  Her reply will be "so what?  We will use the best performed in your tests."

Comment: @whuber. That may be the advertising exec's stance I do not disagree, but I guess I fail to see why hypothesis testing and multi-comparisons is not relevant in my question. My response to the exec would be that we could not determine the best one,  between the two or three top performers due to the sample size we had, so we will go back and run more tests with these that were significantly different than the rest but not between each other and determine if we can find a winner... That is exactly what Hsu's MCB gives you..

Comment: @B If you have the opportunity to do more tests, that changes the picture somewhat.  I doubt that running a series of experiments with multiple comparison hypothesis testing is an efficient use of resources, however.  A good solution would involve balancing the costs of additional testing against the potential gains in discriminating "the best" ad from the second best one.  In other words, this is a problem of decision analysis (with a fairly well characterized loss function), not a problem of hypothesis testing.